# android studio error when trying to read zip file

Tags: android, android-studio

Internal error when trying to read zip file

```
'C:\Users\Tanadon\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\318a0d0c04947313b79aaa7bce7a7501\jars\classes.jar'.
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on the problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't run project show message "Internal error when trying to read zip file 'C:\Users\Tanadon.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\318a0d0c04947313b79aaa7bce7a7501\jars\classes.jar'."

Comment: For help with editing your question so that it is possible for others to help, check out [ask] in the [help].